# Get the radio button drawable of the current version on android

Tags: android, radio-button, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

My main intention is resize the radio button drawables considering the area that is covered by radio group. If I get the drawable of the current android version, I can easily resize it.

Of course I have googled to be able find out the solution. Generally, the people who had the same intention, set a new drawable for the radio button not use the drawable of the radio button.

However, there is a drawback of the solution. As you know that, the drawable can be changed by android version like this.

[image][image]

So the drawback is, if I set my drawable as a radio button icon, it doesn't display like current android version ones. Of course, I can set up drawables for all android versions on their resources folders to be able fix the issue. But I don't want to do that for now.

The other solution is use `getButtonDrawable()`. However, it require the api 23. But min sdk of my project is 21 so it doesn't solve my problem.

As a result, I just want to get radio button drawable of the current android version.